# How do you calculate the Quintile for every row in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to calculate the quintile for every row of a column in Excel.

The resulting value for each row in Excel should be 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.

A value of one will be the top 20%, a value of 5 is the bottom 20%.

This is my current formula which SEEMS to work, but I'm curious to see if anyone has a better way, a UDF, or sees an error in my formula...

```
=ROUNDDOWN(RANK.AVG(A1,$A$1:$A$131,0)/((COUNT(A$1:A$131)+1)/5),0)+1
```

A1 through A131 has the values I'm placing in quintiles.

Thanks

Comment: Can this be done for individual groups within a sheet. That is can the records quintile value be calculate for groups that are based on a value in a separate column?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for, but it might be worth creating a new question.

Comment: Sorry should have shared the link sooner. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310395/how-do-you-calculate-the-quintile-for-groups-of-rows-in-excel

Comment: I would use roundup instead, because your formula, sometimes, will give an extra record (single) with the next category. for instance, it would give a 6 for the last record if the total records count is a pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggested formula works for me......but I think there are several ways you could do this, e.g. use `PERCENTILE` function to get the breakpoints and then match against those with `MATCH`, i.e.

`=MATCH(A1,PERCENTILE(A$1:A$131,{5,4,3,2,1}/5),-1)`

In most cases that gives the same results as your formula but there might be some discrepancies around the boundaries

Comment: Very interesting.  A much cleaner formula than what I produced.  I did see some differences around the boundary lines, but I'll need to dig to see if I can understand the causes and find which one I like better.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the simplicity of `=MATCH(A1,PERCENTILE(A$1:A$131,{5,4,3,2,1}/5),-1)`. I compared the results with a two step manual process that included: 1) calculate 4 percentiles for .2, .4. .6 .8 and 2) a combination of nested IF statements and ended up with the same result as =Match recommended formula in a same of 250 values.

I.E.
STEP 1:

```
=PERCENTILE.INC($J$3:$J$257,0.2) -> Adjust 0.2 to 0.4; 0.6; 0.8 accordingly
```

STEP 2:

```
=IF(J3<=$AB$3,5,
 IF(J3<=$AB$4,4,
 IF(J3<=$AB$5,3,
 IF(J3<=$AB$6,2,
 1))))
```

Compare each value to the calculated =PERCENTILE.INC in STEP 1