# How do you calculate the Quintile for groups of rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I found a partial answer to this question under [How do you calculate the Quintile for every row in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287587/how-do-you-calculate-the-quintile-for-every-row-in-excel). I would like to derive the same quintile data for each row but I need the quintiles to be based on groups that are determined by a value in another column.

Comment: Please show some data by copying and pasting it into the original post, expected return value and what attempts you have done to modify the formula to your needs.

Comment: Do to the confidential nature of the data, I can not share a sample. A general example would be column A contains the values to group by numbered 1-100, column B contains decimal numbers from -10-10. I would like to calculate the quintile placement of the value in B only compared to cells that contain the same value in column A. I have not been able to devise any solutions of my own that do not require manually changing the formula for each value I would like to group by. I have fount that this is not a realistic solution due to the large number of groupings.

Comment: create dummy data then, but one should not expect those who are volunteers to recreate or make up their own data.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=MAX(1,ROUNDUP(10*PERCENTRANK($C:$C,$C2,4),0))
```

Change the value 10 to split into whatever number of groups you need - currently it's making decile groups. Change $C:$C to column with target range of values, and change $C2 to the cell in the first row with target value and autofill down.

Your output will be a split of groups based on the value of 1 being lowest and anything greater higher value in terms of numerical value.

If you mean just row numbers as your ranking criteria, you could insert a new column in A and autofill down numbers that correspond to your row references.